Boost PFC small-signal model for determining transfer function part II
I've followed the theory-based path from my previous Stack Exchange question and am wondering about G_PWM as the cross-over frequency seems dependent on the DC gain (and in turn, directly on G_PWM).  I attempted to select this G_PWM to fit the values given in the answer to the previous question.  I can appreciate where this gain comes from physically, but I don't know how the specific value was arrived at.
Here follows some Python I'm using to plot the plant transfer function and the control-to-output transfer function:
import control as ct
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

P_out = 100      #  W

V_out = 38.0     #  V
V_ac = 24.0      #  V
L = 27 * 1e-6    #  H
R_load = V_out ** 2 / P_out  # ohm
G_PWM = 0.4e-4
C_bulk = 6600e-6

H_0 = V_ac ** 2 / (2 * L) * (R_load / 2) * (G_PWM / V_out)

f_p = 1 / (R_load * C_bulk * np.pi)
omega_p = f_p * 2 * np.pi
print("R_load = {0} H_0 = {1} H_0 = {2} dB omega_p = {3} Hz".format(R_load, H_0, 20 * np.log10(H_0), f_p))

a, b = sp.signal.zpk2tf([], [omega_p], H_0)
#sys1 = H_0 * ct.tf([1], [1, f_p], name='sys1')
sys1 = ct.tf(a, b, name='sys1')

f_p_1 =   0
f_p_2 = 20e2
f_z_1 =  1e2

omega_p_1 = f_p_1 * 2 * np.pi
omega_p_2 = f_p_2 * 2 * np.pi
omega_z_1 = f_z_1 * 2 * np.pi

a, b = sp.signal.zpk2tf([omega_z_1], [omega_p_1, omega_p_2], 1)
sys2 = ct.tf(a, b, name='sys2')
#sys2 = ct.tf([1, f_z_1], [0, 1, f_p_2], name='sys2')

sys3 = ct.series(sys1, sys2, name='sys3')

omega = np.logspace(-1, 3, 500)
ct.frequency_response([sys1, sys2, sys3], omega).plot(initial_phase=0)

Note that I haven't yet tried to form a 'good' compensation transfer function - it's just a placeholder.

Also, if I were to follow the path of the Biricha demo, is my control law described by the content of the yellow box(es), specifically where the voltage feed-forward path, the output voltage, and the demand current are combined?  - I think I don't understand something fundamental here.  I want to map the answer to my original question to the structure found in the original post.
